# Отображение элементов по клику

Tags: javascript, vue.js, маршрутизация

Всем привет,у меня есть навигационное меню,и компоненты ,как по клику по одному из пунктов отобразить именно нужный компонент (v-if)
Вот код меню и ниже его прикреплены компоненты

```
<template>
  <v-container class="card"  fluid grid-list-xl>
    <v-layout wrap align-center>
<v-flex>
  <v-btn class="btn-back"
         block
         color="white"
         :to="'/'"><v-icon dark left>arrow_back</v-icon>Назад</v-btn>
  <v-card class="nav-card">
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="menu-main">
        <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <router-link to="/infocar" >
                <h3><v-icon large>error_outline</v-icon></h3>
                <span class="aaa">Информация о ТС</span>
              </router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <router-link to="/photo" >
                <h3><v-icon large>photo_camera</v-icon></h3>
                <span class="aaa">Фото/Видео</span>
              </router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <router-link to="/damages" >
                <h3><v-icon large>share</v-icon></h3>
                <span class="aaa">Повреждения</span>
              </router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <router-link to="/result" >
                <h3><v-icon large>event_note</v-icon></h3>
                <span class="aaa">Результат осмотра</span>
              </router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <router-link to="/complete" >
                <h3><v-icon large>check_circle_outline</v-icon></h3>
                <span class="aaa">Завершено</span>
              </router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-card>
  <infocar></infocar>
  <photo></photo>
  <damages></damages>
  <result></result>
  <complete></complete>
</v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: Какой адрес страницы на котором компонент который Вы дали?

Comment: path: '/car',
      name: 'Car',
      component: Car,

Comment: Ок, щас пишу ответ для Вас)

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Во-первых: обратитесь к документации vue-router
Во-вторых: зачем вы меню обернули в 3 дива??? от этого смысл отрицательный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это вопрос больше к vue router, там будет правильней задать какие компоненты отображать для данной страницы.

Можно дать этому маршруту детей:

```
{
  path: '/car',
  name: 'Car',
  component: Car,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'infocar',
      component: Infocar
    },
    {
      path: 'photo',
      component: Photo
    },
    {
      path: 'damages',
      component: Damages
    },
    {
      path: 'result',
      component: Result
    },
    {
      path: 'complete',
      component: Сomplete
    }
  ]
},
```

Каждому Вашему компоненту соответсвует маршрут, можно еще дать имя.

Теперь нужно поменять маршруты которые у Вас в `router-link` на подобный вид: `/car/damages`.

И наконец, чтобы отобразить Ваши компоненты надо в `template` для `Car` добавить `<router-view/>` вместо

```
<infocar></infocar>
<photo></photo>
<damages></damages>
<result></result>
<complete></complete>
```

[Вот документация по этому](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html).

Отдельный респект что используете vuetify, очень люблю эту либу)

Comment: Но мне надо чтобы меню всегда было на странице,а менялись только табы(компоненты) по клику на соответствующий пункт

Comment: Я думал их как то скрывать надо через v-if

Comment: У Вас меню должно быть всегда, вы поменяли адреса `<router-link to="/result">` --> `<router-link to="/car/result">` и т.д. Мне кажется Вы что-то пропустили или не так сделали

Comment: Вот пример сделал, все должно работать: https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/RYgzrO?editors=1010

Comment: Адреса я поменял,и роутинг с потомками сделал,на первой вкладке путь правильный но ошибка 404,при переключении на другую путь уже такой car/car/photo

Comment: Все,нашел ошибку)